# Positioning issue in networked a-frame

Tags: three.js, aframe, aframe-networked

I don't know why, but sometimes when multiple users connected they spawn in a different position which I didn't specify anywhere in my code.

```
<a-entity >
        <a-entity
          id="avatar"
          networked="template:#avatar-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
          movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh: true"
          spawn-in-circle="radius:3"
          position="-15 0.770 25"
        >
     
          <a-entity
            class="cam"
            networked="template:#head-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
            camera="active: true"
            position="0 2.5 0"
            look-controls
          >
            <a-sphere
              class="head"
              id="local-avatar"
              visible="true"
              random-color
            ></a-sphere>
          </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

This is the code I've written for the networked entity. I've given **position="-15 0.770 25"**, but camera is spawning in another position. Which ruins all the things like speed, constraints.

```
<script>
    NAF.schemas.getComponentsOriginal = NAF.schemas.getComponents;
    NAF.schemas.getComponents = (template) => {
      if (!NAF.schemas.hasTemplate("#head-template")) {
        NAF.schemas.add({
          template: "#head-template",
          components: [
            "position",
            "rotation",
            {
              selector: ".head",
              component: "material",
              property: "color",
            },
          ],
        });
      }
      const components = NAF.schemas.getComponentsOriginal(template);
      return components;
    };
  </script>
```

This for registering the entity in a-frame.

Comment: check the `spawn-in-circle="radius:3"` source code ;)

Comment: Ok i'll check that

Comment: Hey, I tried to spawn in radius also but after then also it showed me the same issue. Actually, my assets are big full of textures and some have high poly. So, I am thinking maybe due to the loading time of the whole area and assets the networked entity got disturbed. Is that possible?